# How to compile string conditions in aspects

Tags: c#, if-statement, compilation, conditional-statements, postsharp

I have a simple class. And I have to **add** some **conditions** to some methods and properties. For example:

```
public class Example
{
  public Boolean Condition {get; set;}
  public Double ConditionValue {get; set;}

  [Verify("!Condition && ConditionValue>5")]
  public void DoSomthing()
  { ... }
}
```

I want to check the condition (for example, "!Condition && ConditionValue>5") in an aspect attribute. I can not give an action/func into an attribute so I give a simple string. And I need to translate this string into a condition:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyAspectAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (!this.Condition && this.ConditionValue>5) // If-statment from string, this is the problem...
        { ... }
    }
}
```

How I can extract real if-statment from string? I see some solutions, but I'm not sure they fine:

1. Use a runtime compiler, e.g. CSharpCodeProvider.
2. Use a library such as http://flee.codeplex.com/
3. Somthing else...?

How I can do it gracefully? Thanks!

Upd: I have edited the question on the advices...
Upd2: I **don't** try to verification my code, I can do this:

```
public class Example2
    {
      public Boolean Condition {get; set;}

      [LoggingIf("Condition")]
      public void DoSomthing1()
      { ... }

      [PrintReportIf("!Condition")]
      public void DoSomthing2()
      { ... }
    }
```

Comment: Why custom attributes in this case?

Comment: I try to add some logic to class members. It is works, but I'm looking for a fine solution... And how I can add some logic to much(!) properties and methods without attributes..?

Comment: What do you expect will invoke your code once you have it in an attribute? Attributes don't know anything about the members they decorate and nothing 'invokes' attributes. They only specify metadata.

Comment: Postsharp can use this metadata in different ways... =) One way - insert this string as an if-statement(?) into method body...

Comment: @DragonFire - If you're using PostSharp then what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how I can translate my string to real if-statement in my aspect... =(

Comment: @DragonFire PostSharp injects code as a post compilation step. Are you saying you want to hand-roll C# compilation and IL rewriting?

Comment: @DragonFire - That would be valuable information to add to your question. Also be sure to tag your question appropriately.

Comment: For all: I thought that postsharp is only an addition, the subject matter is compile condition... But I'll edit my question at once =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considered using [lambda expressions parser](http://simproexpr.codeplex.com/)? You should be able to do something along the lines:

```
[Verify("(Example e) => !e.Condition && e.Condition > 5")]
public void DoSomthing() 
{ ... }
```

And compile that later using:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyAspectAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
         ExprParser parser = new ExprParser();
         LambdaExpression lambda = parser.Parse(/* Verify string comes here */);
         bool isConditionMet = (bool) parser.Run(lambda, this);

         if (isConditionMet)
         { ... }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

For custom user types, you need to provide namespace (and assembly if type resides in different assembly than the one you call parser from):

```
ExprParser.Using.Add("PersonTypeNamespace");
ExprParser parser = new ExprParser();
LambdaExpression lambda = parser.Parse("(Person p) => p.Name");
var output = parser.Run(lambda, new Person { Name = "DragonFire" });
```

In [download section](http://simproexpr.codeplex.com/releases/view/72072) there's *User guide* file - it provides some extra information on library usage.

Comment: +1 for lambda parser, but I still think he should avoid magic strings for conditions.

Comment: I try to use it, but i have an exception: "Unexpected end" when I'm parsing "(e) => e.Condition" string...

Comment: @DragonFire: you need to add namespaces/assemblies names - check my edit. And actually use full lambda notation, eg. `(Example e) => ...`

Answer (score 1):

Create a set of objects that implements Boolean logic.

- Equals Comparator (takes the name of a property and a value)
- Greater Than Comparator (takes the name of a property and a value)
- And Comparator (takes two comparators)
- Boolean Evaluator (take the name of a boolean property)
- etc, etc

Then have your attribute take one of these objects as a parameter

```
[Verify(new AndComparator(
    new BooleanEvaluator ("Condition"), 
    new GreaterThanComparator("ConditionValue", 5)))]
public void DoSomthing()
```

Comment: I can't do this, becouse I can use nested properties, for example: [Verify("CurrentInfo.User.Account.IsValid")]

Comment: @DragonFire Sure you can, you just need something like [Spring's Expression Evaluation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html); i.e. You walk the string *reflectioning* as you go.  Also, cool user name.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Code Contracts: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/ If having custom attributes is not a must, they may be just what you are looking for.

Code Contracts are good at defining constraints on permissable parameter and return values of methods and optionally checking them at run-time (and even compile time, though it really slows down the IDE)

Comment: I know about contracts, but my task doesn't linked to the software verification...

Answer (score 0):

You already know the formula you want to use so just pass in the values to the aspect.

```
public class MyValidationAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{

public int Val1 { get; set; }
public int Val2 { get; set; }

public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args) 
    { 
        if (this.args.Arguments[0] > Val1) // If-statment from string, this is the problem... 
        { ... } 
    } 


}

[MyValidationAspect(Val1 = 5, Val2 = ...)]
```

Do not try to be so generic/dynamic just make a set of concrete aspects and pass in the values as needed.

Or, you can use Rosylen (Compiler as a Service).

Comment: I have to use different complex conditions... But Rosylen... It is very interesting!!

Comment: @DragonFire Make more than one aspect. Trying to do it so dynamically is not going to get you anything but problems. I can't see a use case where the conditions would change dynamically. You're either doing it wrong or are working very hard at being lazy.

Answer (score -1):

Why not doing something like this:

```
public class Example
{
  public Boolean Condition {get; set;}
  public Double ConditionValue {get; set;}


  public void DoSomthing()
  { 
           Verify.That(!Condition && ConditionValue>5);
           ...
  }
}
```

It's almost the same amount of code, it will be compiled and validated in compile time, you will be able to put things in configuration, verify private members and do complex verifications.

Comment: He's looking to use AOP to write the conditions for him.

Comment: You are correct, and that is one of the many issues about what he is trying to do.

Comment: Roughly the same answer I gave. What is `AOP`?

Comment: @jp2code - [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). PostSharp is just one of the AOP toolkits available for .NET.